# java.io.IOException: listen failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument) when trying to save to public downloads folder with no illegal characters

Tags: java, android

For some reason I am getting `java.io.IOException: listen failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)` when trying to save a file in the Android public downloads folder. There are no illegal characters in the file name:

```
private LocalSocket mServerSocketLocal;

public boolean openManagementInterface(@NonNull Context c) {
    // Could take a while to open connection
    int tries = 8;
    String socketName = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "mgmtsocket");
    Log.d(TAG, socketName);
    // The mServerSocketLocal is transferred to the LocalServerSocket, ignore warning
    mServerSocketLocal = new LocalSocket();
    while (tries > 0 && !mServerSocketLocal.isBound()) {
        try {
            mServerSocketLocal.bind(new LocalSocketAddress(socketName, LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.FILESYSTEM));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // wait 300 ms before retrying
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(ignored));
            }
        }
        tries--;
    }
    try {
        mServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket(mServerSocketLocal.getFileDescriptor());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the result of my `Log.d(TAG, socketName)`:

```
2020-06-18 22:44:20.035 3049-3868/com.my.app D/myapp: /storage/emulated/0/Download/mgmtsocket
```

It is my understanding this is an error that usually happens when there are illegal characters, but I do not see illegal characters.

Comment: It could also happen if the directory wasn't legal, not just via illegal characters but also if it's read-only for example.

Comment: Are you on Android Q?

Comment: `when trying to save a file in the Android public downloads folder.`. Who is trying to save a file?

Comment: @blackapps Yes, I am on Android Q. My bad, it isn't so much saving a file as it is writing to the downloads folder unless I'm misunderstanding the code.

Comment: Try instead with getExternalFilesDir(null).

Comment: I am getting the same error. The only time I do not get the error is when I used getCacheDir(), but I get a different error when I use that ('error 13 permission denied' since in Android Q you cannot execute files in the app's home directory)